# Windows scroll working on scrolling to the top instead of bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I encountered a challenge when trying to activate autoload on scrolling to the bottom. The problem is that the jQuery doesn't work when I scroll to the bottom but when I scroll back to the top, it works.

I tried testing on 1.8.3 instead of the 1.11.1 I was using, the two are actually compressed.

I'm new to jQuery and would appreciate anyone who can assist me. I however tried testing the autoload on another computer and it works fine.

Below is the code

```
function auto_loader(){

    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
        {
              // load your content
              alert("\ola");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `document.documentElement.scrollTop=document.body.scrollTop=9e9;`

Comment: Dandavis, please can you explain what you meant or how to apply your above line to the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have always done this:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
    // Bottom of page
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tq0kxkhs/